# Play in position against BB preflop raiser

Tags: texas-hold-em

I'm on the button, with AJ unsuited.  Blinds 3000/6000. Folded to me, I raise the pot, BB calls. My stack before the start of the hand is around the 110000 mark, slightly lower than the caller.

Flop comes J42 rainbow. BB raises 20000 (pot is 45000 at this point). I call.

Turn is a 6. BB raises 30000 (pot is now 85000). Calling here would have pretty much put me all in on the river, I was concerned about a BB special of two pair or worse still, drawing dead against a low set or even a hit straight.

Do people think this was a correct fold here? Should I have folded on the flop, or perhaps re-raised? Perhaps calling on the flop was a bit silly, the only chance I have of improving my hand is one of the two Js or one of the three As, and an A may not even be enough anyway.

Perhaps also relevant is that I'm in a tournament starting with 22 players or so and down to 10 players. Top three are paid 50/30/20.

**Follow up question:**

How should I have played this if he checked on the flop? Presumably a continuation bet. Lets say it's called? If there's no scare card, push another bet on the turn? Then the river? What size should these bets be? Should they be smaller if there's no obvious draw on the board, but larger if there's a draw to ensure he pays pot odds to chase? What if he's flopped the set and I'm drawing dead? Should I check on the river instead?

Comment: Would you mind posting the follow question as a seperate question and link it back to this one? Its not good if we have to keep coming back and editing our answers. We shouldnt really have two questions within a question.

Answer (score 4):

I think by calling on the flop it makes you look like you have a weak hand, therefore the other guy might be using this to his advantage.

I would have 3-bet the flop that way you know where you stand. If they call then chances are they have at least something. The line you took they could basically be playing any two as they have sensed your weakness.

There are no real scare cards there for me, therefore I think you should probably have got it all in with TPTK to be honest.

Did they show what they had?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to consider a few things:

- Stack of villain
- Villains image (previous hands seen)
- Your own image on the table

If villain stack is much bigger than yours, you are probably better playing the man instead of the hand.

If villains image is very loose, I think you may discard that he even got a made hand because he would have check/raised you if he had it.

In these spots, you must gather more info both pre and post flop

Answer (score 0):

This is a call/call/call situation. Folding is right out of the question since you've got no evidence that he has you beat. If you raise, you fold out all of his bluffing hands and some of the hands he thinks are good (QJ).